# Cannot read QR Code data when it contains large amount of characters - ZXing C#

Tags: c#, qr-code, zxing.net

I have created one QR code by using ZXing c#. But in this there is a problem to read the QR Code Data.
If QR Code data contains less characters, it is working fine. If QR code  data contains large amount of characters, it takes very big time to read and in somecases it is not reading. Here is the code to generate QR Data. Can anyone solve my problem?

```
    public static Bitmap GenerateQRCode(string content)
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                DisableECI = true,
                CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
                Width = 60,
                Height = 60,
                Margin = 1,
                ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H
            };
            var writer = new BarcodeWriter();
            writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            writer.Options = options;
            BitMatrix matrix = writer.Encode(content);             
            int width = matrix.Width;
            int height = matrix.Height;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    if (matrix[x, y])
                    {
                        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                    }
                }
            }             
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [How Many Characters / Digits Can A QR Code Store?](https://qrcode.meetheed.com/question3.php)

Comment: Hi, if you will please add how you read the QR code, we may identify the problem. Since the write part is OK.

Comment: Hi GuyKorol.. I am scanning it from mobile app..

Answer (score 0):

Hi today I had faced same problem.

You can try different QR code format

```
writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
```

In this line you can fine barcode formats for me data Matrix worked. You can try others as well.